# Can Google Maps and KML support larger than 32x32 icons?

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a kml file that I want to display using Google Maps API (version 2).

I want to use an icon that is larger than 32x32.  But when I try this, it looks like the API is resizing the icons to that size.  Can this be done using kml?

If it isn't possible using kml - then what is the best way to do it?

My KML for a point:

```
<Style id="stylemcneil">
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href>http://www.energyjustice.net/map/images/smokestack2-small.gif</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>

<Placemark>
<name>McNeil Biomass Incinerator</name>
<description></description>
<styleUrl>#stylemcneil</styleUrl>
<Point>
<coordinates>-73.208326,44.493526,0.000000</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "kmz" version of geoxml3 uses the native size of the icons (I believe you can scale from there also).

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linkto.html?lat=44.493526&lng=-73.208326&zoom=18&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/mcneil_incinerator_kml.xml)

Renders the kml using native google maps API v3 objects, so doesn't get the performance improvement of tile based rendering (so won't be a good solution if you have lots of points to display).

Comment: That is a good example.  Unfortunately I'm looking for a API version 2 solution.

Comment: Just be aware, APIv2 is deprecated and the google engineers keep reminding everyone that it could be turned off as early as May of 2013.

Comment: Indeed it broke on me few days ago. Don't use geoxml3!

Comment: What broke with geoxml3?  Do you have an example? Google changes the v3 API all the time, they keep breaking and fixing things, it is difficult to keep up.